# Can not find LDAP settings option in odoo 10

Tags: ldap, odoo

I have installed odoo 10 in Ubuntu server 16.04 using the package from http://nightly.odoo.com/10.0/nightly/deb/

Then

- create the database
- install the app: Purchase Management
- install the module: Authentication via LDAP

The manual says that: After installing this module, you need to configure the LDAP parameters in the Configuration tab of the Company details.

But I can not find Configuration tab of Company. I can only find "General Information" Tab.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

debao,

LDAP Setting has been moved to General Setting so from home Screen navigate to "Setting > General Settings > LDAP Parameters" and add new record to add your own LDAP Server. Attached Screen shot for same.

[image]